# Cannot Load Fixed Version Runtime for Webview2

Tags: webview2

[WebView2 site not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66500241/webview2-site-not-loading)

I have followed the above steps in the above link, but still having issues with executing the following lines: CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(@".\Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.96.0.1054.62.x86");

I have placed the runtime folder in my bin/debug where the other dlls reside as shown above. No matter what I do i get the following error: "Couldn't find a compatible Webview2 Runtime installation to host WebViews."

My Nuget Package is version 1.0.1020.30 and Fixed Runtime Version downloaded is 96.0.1054.62.x86.

Answer (score 1):

The key word here is `compatible`.

**You have installed one version from Nuget, yet you try to use another version.**

The solution is to upgrade your Nuget package, so it matches the fixed version, you're trying to use.

To do that, in Nuget package manager, make sure you check '`Include prerelease`'
at the top of the window, now you should be able to select all versions, including prereleases, so the version in project and the version you run are the same.