# How to get json response with WebView2

Tags: c#, wpf, request, response, webview2

I wanna get a json from the response's body of this API:

```js
// http://localhost:3000/api/auth/[token]
export default function Auth(request, response) {
    response.status(200).json({ token: request.query})
}
```

Trying the `WebView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived` event fires just once and the event arg's request Uri parameter is "http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico".

How can I get the response content?

What I did:

```cs
public partial class SignInUserControl : UserControl
{
    public SignInUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitWebView();
    }
    async void InitWebView()
    {
        await WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        WebView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived += CoreWebView2_WebResourceResponseReceived;
    }
    async void CoreWebView2_WebResourceResponseReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream stream = await e.Response.GetContentAsync();
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);
            string re = tr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

What I expect:

```json
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/42sad87aWasFGAS
re = {"token":"42sad87aWasFGAS"} // From CoreWebView2_WebResourceResponseReceived method
```

ps: The WebViewer2 Control is working. So I don't think the problem is related to its initialization.
[working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QoiJ.png)

Comment: For CoreWebView2 initialization, the following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66501901/10024425

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think it's related to initialization. Take a look at the "ps" that I've added to the question.

Comment: The initialization issue may or may not yet be apparent and you've not posted enough code to know if it's an issue for sure. The issue may be more apparent if one deletes the WebView2 _UserDataFolder_ between executions. Nonetheless, CoreWebView2 initialization needs to be performed properly before moving on to anything else.

Comment: Ok. I've just updated with the SignIn User Control's full code. I'm gonna read these answers now.

Comment: If you're getting the web response event handler called for the favicon but not the HTML document you may have a race. If you are setting the WebView2.Source property in XAML to start navigation of the WebView2 then navigation will be started during InitializeComponent but you only attach your WebResourceResponseReceived event handler later after that. You should ensure that you start your navigation after you set the WebResourceResponseReceived event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem really was the WebView initialization. ‍♂️
Thanks to *@user09938* and *@david-risney*

What did I do?
I removed the Source property from the Xaml and made these changes:

```cs
public partial class SignInUserControl : UserControl
{
    public SignInUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitwebView();
    }
    private void InitwebView()
    {
        WebView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
        WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null).GetAwaiter();
        WebView.Source = new Uri("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/NelsonHenrique");
    }
    private void WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived += CoreWebView2_WebResourceResponseReceived;
    }
    private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceResponseReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = e.Response.GetContentAsync().GetAwaiter();
        result.OnCompleted(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var res = result.GetResult();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(res);
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // text: "{\"token\":\"NelsonHenrique\"}"
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not correct. Subscribing to`WebView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` should occur BEFORE the call to `WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()`.